# Implementing Show More - Show Less text on a page

Tags: javascript, html, uiview, tinymce, show-hide

I have a content oriented product. And at one point I display a list of available entities, with their full summary. Now, the said **summary** is the data entered by user using TinyMCE editor (i.e. it can contain HTML tags like img, p, span, ul, li, etc.). As summary can span a few hundred lines, I want to cleanly implement the **Show More-Less** feature, using javascript where I load the summary hidden partially by default, and show rest only when user click, 'Show More'.

It would be great to know, how you guys have or would have implemented it. I am thinking to limit the variety of markup entered by user and use **regex** to split the markup with a span link to load-more (much like facebook does it).

**Note**: I cannot split the text according to number of characters/words, as it can violate markup. I cannot hide the content by limiting height due to `img` tags (which loads later and can alter the height of containing div, and in-turn spoil your height calculations.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the following function to get rid of unwanted html tags.

```
// Strips HTML and PHP tags from a string 
// returns 1: 'Kevin <b>van</b> <i>Zonneveld</i>'
// example 2: strip_tags('<p>Kevin <img src="someimage.png" onmouseover="someFunction()">van <i>Zonneveld</i></p>', '<p>');
// returns 2: '<p>Kevin van Zonneveld</p>'
// example 3: strip_tags("<a href='http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net'>Kevin van Zonneveld</a>", "<a>");
// returns 3: '<a href='http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net'>Kevin van Zonneveld</a>'
// example 4: strip_tags('1 < 5 5 > 1');
// returns 4: '1 < 5 5 > 1'
function strip_tags (str, allowed_tags)
{

    var key = '', allowed = false;
    var matches = [];    var allowed_array = [];
    var allowed_tag = '';
    var i = 0;
    var k = '';
    var html = ''; 
    var replacer = function (search, replace, str) {
        return str.split(search).join(replace);
    };
    // Build allowes tags associative array
    if (allowed_tags) {
        allowed_array = allowed_tags.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/gi);
    }
    str += '';

    // Match tags
    matches = str.match(/(<\/?[\S][^>]*>)/gi);
    // Go through all HTML tags
    for (key in matches) {
        if (isNaN(key)) {
                // IE7 Hack
            continue;
        }

        // Save HTML tag
        html = matches[key].toString();
        // Is tag not in allowed list? Remove from str!
        allowed = false;

        // Go through all allowed tags
        for (k in allowed_array) {            // Init
            allowed_tag = allowed_array[k];
            i = -1;

            if (i != 0) { i = html.toLowerCase().indexOf('<'+allowed_tag+'>');}
            if (i != 0) { i = html.toLowerCase().indexOf('<'+allowed_tag+' ');}
            if (i != 0) { i = html.toLowerCase().indexOf('</'+allowed_tag)   ;}

            // Determine
            if (i == 0) {                allowed = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!allowed) {
            str = replacer(html, "", str); // Custom replace. No regexing
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Usage if content is the editor content. This will keep Spans:

```
var my_clean_content = strip_tags( content, 'span');
```

Answer (score 3):

http://henrik.nyh.se/2008/02/jquery-html-truncate A very neat implementation by this guy.
You can also see working demonstration here http://henrik.nyh.se/examples/truncator/

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd do this with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and use a plugin such as [Text Constrain](http://coxmediagroup.github.com/jquery-textconstrain/).

You can [download it here](https://github.com/coxmediagroup/jquery-textconstrain), or view other similar plugins on the [jQuery site](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/ellipsis).

Answer (score 2):

The best jQuery plugin I've seen that implements this functionality is [Expander](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/). It's also got the advantage of having been around for several years and is still actively maintained as of the time this was written unlike most or all of the other solutions linked to in answers to this question.